# Redrawing only some objects?

Tags: c#, game-engine

I'm trying to learn C#, so I decided to make a little game where monsters siege you. The problem is, I draw the character by using fillrectangle, and same for the trees. The trees start with a random location. They're supposed to stay at the location they first appeared in, but with the code I'm using, they get a new location every timer tick. Help?

Comment: Could you show your current code?

Comment: Maybe ... store the random location for the trees, and then draw them based on that stored location, rather than retrieving a randomized value on-the-fly while drawing?

Comment: hmmm... use a different code?

Comment: Winform? Console with ascii graphics? Web page? OpenGL?

Comment: @Roland forgot DirectX...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you provided no code samples we can just assume you redraw your scene every timer-tick and you might draw the just random-generated locations of the trees at every tick event, a solution like suggested by others is to generate the random coordinates of the trees before you draw the first time, save those coordinates and then when you redraw in your tick event those coordinates will still be the same coordinates as before so your trees will hold position. You might want to read an article about 2d development that explains the 3 basic steps of:

1. Setting everything up/Initialize objects etc and draw the first
   scene.
2. Calculate what changes between 2 shown pictures are made.
3. Draw
   the new picture/Update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the trees to stay at the same location, you should tell your program to do so.

Comment: This isn´t an answer at all as it does not add any useful statements to the solution. It is however - at its best - a comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere you're right. but his answer is in its complexity same level as the question. so...

Comment: @HimBromBeere My comment is that I am certain that OP did not explicitly program to keep the trees at the same location, otherwise they would.